# Java trabalhando JSON

Tags: java, json

Bom, estou iniciando meus estudos em java, por este motivo estou meio cru nas possibilidade, nas bibliotecas e outras qualidades que existem na programação `JAVA`. Dentro muitas duvidas gostaria de entender se existe alguma forma de pegar um objeto do tipo `ResultSet` que no caso é o retorno de um `query` feita da seguinte maneira:

```
 ResultSet rs_tbl_CONTROLE_SINCRONISMO = con.query("SELECT * FROM DB_EGLISE.tbl_CONTROLE_SINCRONISMO;");
```

E transformar em um formato JSON ?

Existe alguma biblioteca que faça isto para mim ?

Comment: @Marconi meu problema está sendo porque não sei quais as tabelas que pode retornar de meu SQL, ai mediante a isto como devo transformar para JSON ?

Comment: Sei quais tabela porém não sei os campos que irão voltar

Comment: Campos ou dados?

Comment: Os dados retornados

Answer (score 1):

Entao, voce primeiramente tera de fazer uma iteração nos resultados do ResultSet

```
while (rs_tbl_CONTROLE_SINCRONISMO.next()) {
}
```

e cada campo da tabela voce deve pegar sabendo o tipo de dados.
por exemplo: rs_tbl_CONTROLE_SINCRONISMO.getIt("id");

voce pode fazer isso e ir populando um Objeto java

depoi de populado o Objeto existe algumas bibliotecas que transformam Objeto Java para Json e Json para Objeto Java, por exemplo o Gson https://github.com/google/gson